# certbot --apache returning "Failed redirect for example.com", "Unable to set the redirect enhancement for example.com."

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am running this:

```
certbot --apache
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: example.com
2: www.example.org
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate numbers separated by commas and/or spaces, or leave input
blank to select all options shown (Enter 'c' to cancel): 1,2

Certificate not yet due for renewal

You have an existing certificate that has exactly the same domains or certificate name you requested and isn't close to expiry.
(ref: /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf)

What would you like to do?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: Attempt to reinstall this existing certificate
2: Renew & replace the certificate (may be subject to CA rate limits)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel): 1
Deploying certificate
Successfully deployed certificate for example.com to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf
Successfully deployed certificate for www.example.com to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf
Failed redirect for example.com
Unable to set the redirect enhancement for example.com.

NEXT STEPS:
- The certificate was saved, but could not be installed (installer: apache). After fixing the error shown below, try installing it again by running:
  certbot install --cert-name example.com

Unable to find corresponding HTTP vhost; Unable to create one as intended addresses conflict; Current configuration does not support automated redirection
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

Where can I find the corresponding HTTP vhost settings to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at https://www.linode.com/community/questions/23559/dont-delete-a-certificate-for-a-domain-via-certbot. I had used `certbot --apache -d domain.com`, which according that that page it is a "DON'T DO THIS". They recommend instead to use `certbot certonly --standalone -d domain.com`. That fixed my problem, simply using the following:

```
# certbot certonly --standalone -d example.com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Requesting a certificate for example.com

Successfully received certificate.
Certificate is saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem
Key is saved at:         /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem
This certificate expires on 2024-01-28.
These files will be updated when the certificate renews.
Certbot has set up a scheduled task to automatically renew this certificate in the background.

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:
 * Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
 * Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

The link I mentioned also says: "If you want the urls domain.com and [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to be equivalent, you would acquire the cert like this: `sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d domain.com,www.domain.com`".